# PdfTeX not compiling in TeX Live with Texmaker - Shows error

Tags: errors, pdftex, compiling

LOG FILE:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.12.17) 18 DEC 2019 10:06
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
```

Comment: Income tax is usually only due around May of the following year, so you still have plenty of time left to figure out how to use “taxmaker”.

Comment: And what exactly are we suppose to do with this part from the log?

Comment: We are flattered that you think we can read minds `:-)` but, unfortunately, most of us can't. You are neither showing the code nor the error. How are we supposed to help?